# Where does the TFS Office integration excel plugin store the server names

Tags: tfs

Where does the TFS Office integration excel plugin store the server names so that they are persistent the next time the user logs in. Right now when a user logs in with a Citrix desktop the settings for the server name are not persisting. The Citrix team has asked me for the location where this information is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is configured in the **Team** tab in Excel. And its name is auto generated by the TFS excel plugin according to the server configured. If it is not authorized to access the TFS from the Excel in the citrix desktop, the server name will not be displayed.

You can try add the TFS in the Excel in the citrix desktop. See below steps:

**Team** tab-->**Configure**-->**Server Connection**-->**Ok** to reconnect document to server instance-->
**Servers**-->**Add**. See below screenshot.

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel-on-prem) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Let me clarify, The extension works in Citrix, but the next day when the user logs in, the plugin does not remember the server settings. Our Citrix environment is "refreshed" every night so thos settings get wiped. The team uses something called ApppSense that will persist the configuration as AppSense stores that data for the user. I need to know where the pluging store those settings.

Comment: It looks the settings are stored as part of the document, and arenot visible to end users. Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings#persisting-add-in-state-and-settings-with-the-office-javascript-api).

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear, I wanted to know where the plugin/extension stores the server names the next time a user opens a new blank excel. The plugin stores the server name in the registry.

Comment: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\server_name]
"IsHosted"="False"
"InstanceId"="7613a471-845f-4626-b715-facca415de22"
"Type"=dword:00000000
"Uri"="http://server_name_here:8080/tfs"